# Enable 24-bit color when using Emacs over SSH connection on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, colors, emacs, raspberry-pi

I am using Emacs on a Raspberry Pi device, and I’m connecting to the device over SSH. Is it possible to enable 24-bit color with using Emacs over this connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this working. I’m using [Blink shell](https://blink.sh/) to connect to a Raspberry Pi device with Emacs 26.1 installed over SSH. This explicitly does NOT work for the release version of Mosh, as [Mosh doesn’t 24-bit true color support yet](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/961). However, you can build Mosh from source to get this working over a Mosh connection, [details are here](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/961#issuecomment-565741393).

The [Emacs FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/efaq.html#Colors-on-a-TTY) has the full instructions, but I found that I had to use:

```
$ export TERM=xterm-24bits
```

instead of

```
$ export TERM=xterm-24bit
```

to set the terminal to use 24-bit color.

With that done, I have 24-bit colors when starting Emacs as I normally would:

```
$ emacs
```